# Extract data from complex JSON and convert into a single JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got some complex JSON which looks something like this:

```
{
  "memberdetails": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "label": "General Details",
      "visible": true,
      "properties": [
        {
          "label": "Address",
          "description": "Residential or Postal Address",
          "view": "textarea",
          "config": {},
          "hideLabel": false,
          "validation": {
            "mandatory": false,
            "pattern": null
          },
          "id": 0,
          "value": "test 1",
          "alias": "address",
          "editor": "Umbraco.TextboxMultiple",
          "visible": "true"
        },
        {
          "label": "State",
          "description": "State of residence",
          "view": "textbox",
          "config": {},
          "hideLabel": false,
          "validation": {
            "mandatory": false,
            "pattern": null
          },
          "id": 0,
          "value": "test 2",
          "alias": "state",
          "editor": "Umbraco.Textbox",
          "visible": "true"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "label": "Other Details",
      "visible": true,
      "properties": [
        {
          "label": "Address",
          "description": "Residential or Postal Address",
          "view": "textarea",
          "config": {},
          "hideLabel": false,
          "validation": {
            "mandatory": false,
            "pattern": null
          },
          "id": 0,
          "value": "test_otherdetails1 ",
          "alias": "aliastest",
          "editor": "Umbraco.TextboxMultiple",
          "visible": "true"
        },
        {
          "label": "State",
          "description": "State of residence",
          "view": "textbox",
          "config": {},
          "hideLabel": false,
          "validation": {
            "mandatory": false,
            "pattern": null
          },
          "id": 0,
          "value": "test_otherdetails2",
          "alias": "aliastest2",
          "editor": "Umbraco.Textbox",
          "visible": "true"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "label": " Details",
      "visible": true,
      "properties": [
        {
          "label": "Address",
          "description": "Residential or Postal Address",
          "view": "textarea",
          "config": {},
          "hideLabel": false,
          "validation": {
            "mandatory": false,
            "pattern": null
          },
          "id": 0,
          "value": " Details1",
          "alias": "Details1Test",
          "editor": "Umbraco.TextboxMultiple",
          "visible": "true"
        },
        {
          "label": "State",
          "description": "State of residence",
          "view": "textbox",
          "config": {},
          "hideLabel": false,
          "validation": {
            "mandatory": false,
            "pattern": null
          },
          "id": 0,
          "value": "Details2",
          "alias": "Details12est",
          "editor": "Umbraco.Textbox",
          "visible": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to extract the `alias` and `value` items from the JSON and put them into a single JObject like this:

```
{
  "address": "test 1",
  "state": "test 2",
  "aliastest": "test_otherdetails1 ",
  "aliastest2": "test_otherdetails2",
  "Details1Test": " Details1",
  "Details12est": "Details2"
}
```

Is there an easy way to do using Json.Net?  Note the `alias` values will all be distinct in the actual JSON.

Comment: What you have there is 3 separate arrays, not 1.  You will not be able to convert these into a single JObject because JObject does not allow duplicate keys (there are three `address` and three `state` keys shown).

Comment: @Brian .. Ok. So, if we distinct keys is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.

Comment: @Brain.. any suggestion or idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Well, it seems to me that this question is actually an extension of the [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36216933/10263) you asked, which was looking for a slightly different format (single array with one object per array).  So which one do you really want?  Also, which JSON are you really starting from?   That one or this one?

Comment: @Brain.. you got me right :) Yes its an extension to that question only. JSON is same,actually the result i am getting over there is JArray with different result set format which i need to send to .So, i was trying to convert it into single jobject .

Comment: @BrianRogers ..  this is the Fiddle:[link]( https://dotnetfiddle.net/3BNRAp) where i am getting JArray and i am trying to convert it into single Jobject. Thanks for understtanding.

Comment: OK, if you want a single JObject, the resulting keys will need to be distinct, like I said, or else the conversion to JObject will not be possible. Can you edit the JSON in the fiddle so that it results in the distinct keys you want in the output?  From there I can take it and show how to convert to a single JObject.

Comment: @BrianRogers .. yes keys will be distinct. Please find the Fiddle:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/lxxmq6    . Thanks

Comment: OK, I've edited your question to reflect what I think you're actually trying to do, and provided an answer.  (If I got it wrong, please edit the question to correct it.)  I'm going to close your other question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can transform your JSON like this:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

JObject result = new JObject(
    obj["memberdetails"]
        .SelectMany(jt => jt["properties"])
        .Select(jt => new JProperty((string)jt["alias"],jt["value"]))
);

Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pyAxhu

Comment: Thanks a lot Brain :)Can you please suggest a proper channel for learning json.net?

Comment: @Harshit Unfortunately, no.  You can try searching for tutorials, or look at [samples in the documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm).  There are also over [4800 answered questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjson.net%5D+answers%3A1) on SO related to Json.Net; you could try reading some of those to get an idea of what issues people run into and how to solve them.  But I think the best way to learn something is to actually try it.  Start with example programs and play with them, change them, try to understand how they work.  If you get stuck, ask for help.